# First Cypress test always fails no matter what in CircleCI

Tags: docker-compose, continuous-integration, cypress, circleci

I have a CircleCI config in which I am running machine executor, starting up my application using docker-compose, then running E2E tests in Cypress, that are not in docker, against this app. Cypress basically spins up a headless browser and tries to hit the specified url.

Now, no matter what my first test always fails. I have created 10 tests that just hit the root url and click a button. I have those tests run first. First one always fails.

The error is

```
CypressError: cy.visit() failed trying to load:

http://localhost:3000/
```

Which basically means there was no response or a 4-500

I though the app might not be ready yet, so I added a sleep before starting tests. I set that to 9 minutes (10 minutes times out on CircleCI). First test failed. I ratcheted that down to 2 minutes. First test fails.

Again to be clear, the first 10 tests are the same, so it’s not test specific.

### Update

I have [crossposted this to the CircleCI forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/first-test-always-fails-no-matter-what-the-test-is/31819).

Comment: When posting questions in multiple places, please link each one to all the others. This will help readers assess whether you have received answers already, and thus will save them wasting their time in the case where you are no longer in need of help.

Answer (score 1):

I think your server isn’t ready.

Before run cypress test, you have to wait for server.

If so, don't use sleep.
You can use wait-on or start-server-and-test.
You can check this doc. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/continuous-integration.html#Boot-your-server

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I strongly suspect it is not that the server isn't ready, because, as I describe, only one test fails at 2 minutes, and only one test fails at 9 minutes.  None the less, I will try wait on as that may just jog the system into reacting. I'll keep us posted

Comment: So it appears that "wait-on" is using the spread syntax either for array or for object, the error doesn't make that clear, and I guess either circleci is not using a late enough version of node or wait-on has published a module that actually needs to be babel'd which woudl be pretty bad.  In either case that s don't work.

Answer (score 0):

So TJ Jiang was close with his answer.  Unfortunately wait-on doesn't work with CircleCI.

So I wrote my own,

`timeout 540 bash -c 'while [ $(curl -s -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} localhost:3000) != "200" ]; do sleep 15; done' || false`

This pings the url every 15 seconds for 9 minutes till it receives a http status code of 200 or it exits.

To be specific I wrote a Makefile target that uses that line above, I don't know how just pasting that in config.yml would work.

So running this as a step prior to running the cypress tests does in fact make it so all 5 identical tests pass.

So now it pings for about 3 1/2 minutes then goes through.  I had tested with sleep up to 9 minutes and always the same result.  So I don't know why this works better than sleep but it clearly does.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it by server/route/wait. I first start the server, then create a rout alias, wait for it to call the Api endpoint (which triggers the app to fill the dom) then do the rest (cy.get/click).

Example before:

```
cy.get('myCssSelector')
```

**After server/route/wait:**

```
cy.server()
cy.route('GET', '*/project/*').as('getProject')

cy.wait('@getProject')
   .then(resp => {
     expect(resp.status).to.eq(201)
   })

cy.get('myCssSelector')
```